# How to Prevent copy from protected excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to protect some of the columns from my excel. I tried this code mentioned below but its not working can anyone help me to out of this issue.

```
Sub ARCProtectPwdRFQ()

ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="arc"
Cells.Locked = False

ActiveSheet.Range("A1", "D100").Locked = True
Columns("I:I").EntireColumn.Locked = True
ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="arc", UserInterFaceOnly:=True   'DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: You have to clarify *what* is not working - otherwise it is not possible to help

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub ARCProtectPwdRFQ()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = Sheet1

    With ws
        .Unprotect Password:="arc"
        .Cells.Locked = False

        .Range("A1", "D100").Locked = True
        .Columns("I:I").EntireColumn.Locked = True

        .Protect Password:="arc", UserInterFaceOnly:=True, _
        DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True

        .EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells
    End With
End Sub
```

To prevent copying, simply disable the selection of the locked cells using `.EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells`.

Also avoid the use of `Activesheet` unless and until it is absolutely necessary. Use objects.